# How to create a Data frame with n columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a Data Frame with 1 row and n columns but the column names need to change with my n.
So for example if my n = 3, I want a Data Frame with 1 Row and 3 columns and the column names should be A1 A2 A3.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize empty data frame (lot of columns at the same time) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501345/how-to-initialize-empty-data-frame-lot-of-columns-at-the-same-time-in-r) Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/50706183/5325862

Answer (score 0):

```
ncol <- 3
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = ncol)), paste0("A", seq(ncol)))

df

  A1 A2 A3
1 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

```
# define n
n <- seq(1:3)

# create dataframe
myData = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(n))) 
# column names 
columns <- paste0("A", n)
# bring together
names(myData) <- columns
myData
```

output:

```
A1 A2 A3
1 NA NA NA
```